# How do I automatically save pictures to my SD card? (Samsung galaxy s3 mini)

Tags: sd-card, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I just got a new SD card and I want all of the pictures I save (from Tumblr, screenshots, etc...) to automatically save into their respective folders that I made on the SD card. Can I do this, or do I have to move them each time I save?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `settings > storage` then select default writing disk to sd card.